# Quicksight sharing dashboard with minimum privilege

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-quicksight

I have a Quicksight dashboard in my AWS account. I need to share this dashboard with other stakeholders of our project. These members are not a part of our AWS account.

How can I share the dashboard with other team members which are not a part of same AWS account with minimum privilege ? Do the members need Quicksight account to view a dashboard ? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one way to share dashboards to external users not from your account, i.e. to [embed your dashboards](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/embed-interactive-dashboards-in-your-application-with-amazon-quicksight/) to some web application. That way, only the person accessing your web app can access the dashboards.

Alternatively, you may invite users to your account with minimal privileges. [More details here](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-quicksight-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/sharing-a-dashboard.md).